# Pass function as prop to a child functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a callback function to a child that's a functional component so that it can update the parent. I'm getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: updateVal is not a function` inside the child (I'll add a comment to the line where it happens). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.updateVal = this.updateVal.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      val: 'A',
    };
  }
  
  updateVal(newVal: string) {
    this.setState({ val: newVal });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child 
        updateVal={this.updateVal}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

```
export function Child(updateVal: any) {
  
  const handleSelectorChange = (event: any) => {
    updateVal(event.target.value); // error here: updateVal is not a function
  };

  return (
      <Select onChange={handleSelectorChange} >
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
      </Select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are passed to functional components as an object, not as individual arguments. In short, given the JSX:

```
<Child
  foo={fooValue}
  bar={barValue}
/>
```

you can expect the child to receive an object that holds `{ foo: fooValue, bar: barValue }` in its props.

The first argument to your functional component is that object. You can retrieve the desired value from it directly:

```
export function Child(props) {
  const updateVal = props.updateVal;
  // ...
}
```

or by [destructing it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```
export function Child({ updateVal }) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `Child(updateVal: any)`. You need to update it: `Child({updateVal}: any)`

Comment: While you're technically not wrong, this doesn't really explain what the problem is, nor outline how to avoid the same problem in the future.

Comment: This fixed it, but could you explain why that worked?